# How to print every member of a structure

Tags: c++, struct

Suppose I have a structure with 50 integers. Is there a way to print out the value of every integer without having to manually type it out?

Example:

```
struct foo
{
  int one; //= 1
  int two; //= 2
  int three; //= 3
  ...
  int fifty; //= 50
};
int main()
{
    foo bar;
    int dream;
    cout << someThing(bar) //prints 12345...50
}
```

edit:
I realize data like this should be stored in an array, this is just a hypothetical question.
I am just curious if something like this exists.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have such a structure. That's what arrays are for.

Comment: A structure with 50 ints in it? Rethink your design at once

Comment: How can you assign int one = 1; values to structure member directly?

Comment: I just typed the one = 1 thing quickly for the sake of the example. Its just suppose to give you an idea of what im asking about.

Comment: You can do this in higher level languages like C#. It's called reflection.

Comment: You can also do it in C and C++. It's called "knowing how your compiler works under the covers" :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you probably should have used arrays for such a thing in the first place since that would have made this task so much easier :-)

However, you could *try* casting the structure into an array and printing that out. There's no guarantee it will work in every implementation since it may be that the structure gets padded differently to an array, though I couldn't imagine *why,* but you may get lucky:

```
int *base = (int*)(&bar.one);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    std::cout << "Item #" << (i + 1) << " = " << base[i] << '\n';
```

By way of example, the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  int one, two, three, four;
};

int main() {
    foo bar;
    bar.one = 42;
    bar.two = 314159;
    bar.three = 271828;
    bar.four = 1414;

    int *base = (int*)(&bar.one);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        std::cout << "Item #" << (i + 1) << " = " << base[i] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

outputs this:

```
Item #1 = 42
Item #2 = 314159
Item #3 = 271828
Item #4 = 1414
```

in my environment (Debian 7, g++ 4.7.2):

But, if you want to treat them like an array, they really should *be* an array.

Comment: Isn't it an error to initialize members of a structure in its definition? The code snippet in the question is plain wrong and should be corrected.

Comment: @ajay This works since C++11 and is a great way to give simple structs a predefined initialization without writing your own constructor.

Comment: I will change that, I meant the entire thing as sudo code.

Comment: Looks like it is valid in C++11 but is not in earlier C++ standards neither in C. The compiler emits the following warning without the switch `-std=c++11`: `warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11`.

Comment: will the same process work, if structure have different elements of different datatypes ?

Comment: @rajenpandit: unlikely since it wouldn't then necessarily map cleanly to an array. Of course, if you know the structure, you can make the pointer casting more complex.

Comment: And it appears most of the comments above should have been made on the _question._ I'm not doing the C++11 init thing in this answer.

Comment: It would be pedantically UB to iterate over the members this way.

Comment: @rajenpandit I came up with this example: https://onlinegdb.com/0hcl5q1wR `struct abc1 { int a; char c; float f; } *p = (struct abc *)&x;` `for (int i=1; i<=1000;i++,p++)` `printf("%d: %d,'%c',%0.0f\n",i,p->a,p->c,p->f);` which is probably UB but it worked for me.

Comment: @Jarod42: almost certainly. Hence my comment "There's no guarantee it will work in every implementation ...".