# Print All member of a struct in C++/CPP

Tags: c++, gcc

I have below struct

```
struct abc
{
 int a1;
 char c1;
 float f1;
 
 int a2;
 char c2;
 float f2;

 .
 .
 .
 

 int aa1000;
 char cc1000;
 float ff1000;
} ;
```

all member of struct has different names. here for the sake of typing I have just denoted them as a1, a2 , c1, c2 and so on ... .

so array can't be created for members.

This struct is having more than 1 thousand members.
I want to print all of them in a single go for debugging purposes.

Stuct is very large otherwise a simple print function could have been written which will print each and every member.
But here,  there many struct of this kind having more than thousand members and writing print function for each of them is not feasible.

Is there any way to dump/print all member of struct ?

Comment: First refactor that code! It is going to be unmaintainable

Comment: Why do you have a struct like that and not a container, e.g. an `std::array<std::tuple<int, char, float> >`?!

Comment: Having numbers in variables is a huge red flag, just use arrays.

Comment: 1000 members ?? But this is repeating the same pattern... You should create a `struct acf{int a; char c; float f;};` and then have a `struct abc` that holds a `std::array<acf, 1000>`. It would be waaayyy simpler, shorter, easier to read and maintain, etc...

Comment: Consider something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033012/how-to-print-every-member-of-a-structure

Comment: @Fareanor: AoS or SoA btw, `std::array<int, 1000> as; std::array<char, 1000> cs; std::array<float, 1000> fs;` might be better.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right. It'd be a better in memory.

Comment: @Jarod42 Depends on the context of a,c,f. If they are members of a logical struct then a struct if they're unrelated entities then yes seperate arrays

Comment: @PKramer: *"Depends of context"*, yes for sure. but the logical struct is not sufficient. jobs done on the array(s) might be more important, or space waste because of padding. There are even some libraries which allow to switch between SoA and AoS simply.

Comment: @Jarod42 Valid points too :)

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033012/how-to-print-every-member-of-a-structure I came up with this: https://onlinegdb.com/0hcl5q1wR `struct abc1 { int a; char c; float f; } *p = (struct abc *)&x;` `for (int i=1; i<=1000;i++,p++)` `printf("%d: %d,'%c',%0.0f\n",i,p->a,p->c,p->f);` which is probably UB but it worked for me.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah One comment only : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud. This will just get worse over time.

Comment: @PepijnKramer You can use separate arrays and defer the logic to accessors: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/7jqnqzo7v)

Comment: @Fareanor Yes that will do, best of both worlds :)

Answer (score 2):

Refactor direction :

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct xyz
{
    int a{0};
    char c{'x'};
    float f{};
};

struct abc
{
    std::array<xyz, 1000> records;
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const xyz& record)
{
    os << "a = " << record.a << ", c = " << record.c << ", f = " << record.f << "\n";
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const abc& data)
{
    std::size_t n{ 0 };
    for (const auto& record : data.records)
    {
        os << "record[" << n++ << "] : ";
        os << record;
    }

    return os;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    abc data;
    // data.x1 -> abc.x[0] etc...
    // data.x2 -> abc.x[1] etc...
    // data.x3 -> abc.x[2] etc...

    std::cout << data;
}
```